# Laravel Validation is not throwing the error of the field that is really faulty

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a validation block as follows:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'id'        => 'required|string|unique:user,id|max:32',
    'email'     => 'required|email|max:191',
    'name'      => 'nullable|string',
    'birthDate' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d',
    'countryId' => 'nullable|integer',
    'city'      => 'nullable|string|max:191',
    'address'   => 'nullable|string',
    'zipCode'   => 'nullable|string|max:191',
    'phone'     => 'nullable|string',
]);
```

I'm sending data like this:

```php
{
    "id": "nJy8zWQ6VuptDFNA",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "name": "name",
    "birthDate": "1980-01-01",
    "countryId": 1481,
    "city": "a city",
    "address": "this is an address",
    "zipCode": "123400",
    "phone": 09876554321
}
```

I am sending the *phone* field as improper data-type. Then the response is like that the *phone* field is wrong type.

But I get this response:

```php
{
    "id": [
        "The id field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ]
}
```

I can't find the problem here.

Comment: Show your view.

Comment: How are you sending the input? You are not sending it correctly and that is why it's showing error. And I don't think the error is incorrect

Comment: I am posting like this:
`-H 'Authorization: ********' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "id": "nJy8zWQ6VuptDFNA",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "name": "name",
    "birthDate": "1980-01-01",
    "countryId": 1481,
    "city": "a city",
    "address": "this is an address",
    "zipCode": "123400",
    "phone": 09876554321
 }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending a valid JSON body.

This code:

```php
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "id": "nJy8zWQ6VuptDFNA",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "name": "name",
    "birthDate": "1980-01-01",
    "countryId": 1481,
    "city": "a city",
    "address": "this is an address",
    "zipCode": "123400",
    "phone": 09876554321
}
JSON;
json_decode($json);
echo json_last_error();
```

Will echo 4 which is the code for `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` meaning that is a syntax error.

The error is that numbers can't be prefixed with 0 in JSON. It's probably because in JavaScript prefixing with 0 indicates an octal number but allowing this in JSON could hurt portability.

Unfortunately, the default behaviour of the PHP built-in JSON parser is to return null on a syntax error and not say anything else about it.

This could potentially be a Laravel idea to allow validating that the entire input is correctly formatted JSON as part of the validation to ensure that we have means of checking that what we send is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The phone number is missing the quotes and its making the json invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to add the `"`(quotes) for all the values, you've missed it for `phone`

it supposed to be like this

```
{
    "id": "nJy8zWQ6VuptDFNA",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "name": "name",
    "birthDate": "1980-01-01",
    "countryId": 1481,
    "city": "a city",
    "address": "this is an address",
    "zipCode": "123400",
    "phone": "09876554321"
}
```